# How to update and check data if exists in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code

and Im trying to update the user and check it first if it is already existed.
and my problem is it also check itself as existed user.

How to prevent checking itself as an existed data before updating in PDO?

```
try
{
    $stmt = $crud->runQuery("SELECT user_name, user_email FROM tbl_login WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_name'=>$user_name, ':user_email'=>$user_email));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['user_name']==$user_name)
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <strong>Error!</strong> Username is already taken!
            </div>";
    }
    else if($row['user_email']==$user_email)
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Error!</strong> Email is already taken!
                </div>";
    }
    else
    {
        if($crud->update($edit_id,$user_name,$user_email))
        {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                <strong>Great!</strong> Record was updated successfully <a href='index.php'>Dashboard</a>!
                </div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
                <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating record !
                </div>";
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Exclude the current user's id that is editing the value  `SELECT user_name, user_email
    FROM tbl_login 
    WHERE user_id != :user_id AND
    (user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email)`

Answer (score 1):

It is easy as you imagine. I won't give you the exact code but I'll give you the logic. You don't have to check data entries 1 by 1. I know you already knew it.

1. Get the username
2. Run a query that will find the username.
3. Check if the query returned more than 1 row.
4. It returned more than 1 row?
5. If yes, the username exists. Update it.
6. Else, it do not exist. Nothing to update.

Goodluck!

Comment: Excelent idea. I dont have to use long long long code

Comment: Yep! You just call `var.rowCOunt()` and its good. Goodluck on your project!

Comment: It's not me. maybe the other viewers

Comment: No worries mate!